# Grunt command line is not working

Tags: gruntjs

When I try to run

> $ grunt

it showing this error

> Fatal error: unable to find local grunt

I have installed grunt in my project by using this command

> > npm install -g grunt-cli

can any one tell me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sudo as sometimes it is just because of access-permission issues. Also check if you are running the command in your project's root directory.

so try

> sudo npm install -g grunt-cli

it might also be a good idea to update your update existing npm before installing  grunt-cli by running

> npm update -g npm